# Multidimensional associative unique

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2x multidimensional array's as show below:

```
$x = [
        0=>[
            'a',
            'b'
        ],

        1=>[
            'c',
            'd'
        ],

        2=>[
            'e',
            'f'
        ]
    ];

    $y = [
        0=>[
            'b',
            'a'
        ],

        1=>[
            'g',
            'h'
        ],

        2=>[
            'i',
            'j'
        ]
    ];
```

I would like to merge the 2x array's (x and y) with an output like this

```
$xy = [
        0=>[
            'c',
            'd'
        ],
        1=>[
            'e',
            'f'
        ],
        2=>[
            'g',
            'h'
        ],
        3=>[
            'i',
            'j'
        ]
    ];
```

As you can see, `$x[0]` is equal to `a,b` and `$y[0]` equal to `b,a` and they are duplicated. I would like to know if it's possible for a,b as same as b,a , I don't know how to get my code to look like this. I want to eliminate my duplicated array (a,b != b,a). Any duplication are not allowed, is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you exactly what you've requested. I've used multiple `foreach()` loops to test if the value is firstly part of the `$Y` array, if so then remove from both arrays using `unset()`. I've then merged the two arrays together, removed the empty array dimensions and reset the key count.

```
$x = [0=>['a','b'],1=>['c','d'],2=>['e','f']];
$y = [ 0=>['b','a'],1=>['g','h'],2=>['i','j']];

foreach ($x as $key=>$value) {

    foreach($x[$key] as $k=>$v) {

        $search = array_search($v, $y[$key], true); //Find if value is equal to value in Y using a search

     if ($search !== false) { //If so then remove value

         unset($y[$key][$search]); //Remove from Array Y
         unset($x[$key][$search]); //Remove from Array X

      } 

    }
}


$newArray = array_merge($x, $y); //Merge two arrays together

foreach($newArray as $key => $value) { //Remove empty dimensions from Array

    if (count($newArray[$key]) <= 0) {

        unset($newArray[$key]);

    }

}


$newArray = array_values($newArray); //Re-Number Keys so there in order


var_dump($newArray); //Array Output
```

**Output**

```
{
    [0] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(1)
        "c" [1] => string(1)
        "d"
    }[1] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(1)
        "e" [1] => string(1)
        "f"
    }[2] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(1)
        "g" [1] => string(1)
        "h"
    }[3] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(1)
        "i" [1] => string(1)
        "j"
    }
}
```

***Edit***

*Added `unset()` to remove value from both arrays as it's mentions that you would **NOT** like to have duplicate data from either array shown in new array.*